# How do I add a Reference to a new Windows Forms Project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I do not see a way to add a reference to a new Windows Forms project using Visual Studio 2019.

[image: VS Project]

- Right-Click the project
- Add >
- New Item...

[image: add item]

And as you see below there is no option to add a reference.

[image: no reference]

I can load old projects that already have Reference links in them, right-click, and reference more assemblies or projects, but I cannot seem to add references to a new project.

[image: old project]

Does anyone know a trick to this? Did I miss something on the install?

**= = = = = = = = = SOLVED! = = = = = = = = =**
**= = = = = = = = = SOLVED! = = = = = = = = =**
**= = = = = = = = = SOLVED! = = = = = = = = =**

The accepted answer was not 100% what I wanted, but it showed me how to do it on my own.

What I needed to start with was a Windows Forms App using the .NET Framework instead of .NET Core.

[image: .NET Framework Project]

Since Visual Studio 2019 has a new startup screen, I was busy looking for the Windows Forms template and did not notice that I needed to select what platform to build on.

The screenshot above is provided to quickly guide others who come across this same issue.

Comment: Sorry but this is a bit confusing.  Are you trying to add a new form to your existing project or are you trying to add a reference to another project?

Comment: Right click `References` and then `Add Reference...` then from the popup you'll see `Projects`

Comment: @Steve I want to add `System.Data.SqlClient` to the project for some familiar debugging.

Comment: @kshkarin VS2019 does not have `References` anymore under the WinForm project ...or at least mine doesn't!

Comment: Then you should right click on References and choose Add Reference...

Comment: @Steve the screenshot showing References is from an old project that was ported over to VS2019. New projects created in VS2019 do not come with References.

Comment: @jp2code but the screenshot clearly shows `References` in the solution, is that from your computer or just a random image?

Comment: @kshkarin, that is for the old project that we ported over to VS2019. New WinForm projects do not have this

Comment: @jp2code maybe you created a .NET Core WinForms app instead of .NET Framework ? Does your solution show `Dependencies` ?

Comment: I see, that's a NET CORE Winforms project. You need to right click on dependencies and use the Nuget Manager to reference the SqlClient lib

Comment: But if you need to integrate it with other projects in a solution where you use the Net Framework then discard this project and re-create it using the NetFramework Winforms project template

Comment: @Steve, you and kshkarin are neck-and-neck on this. I think you 2 are right. This is probably a .NET Core WinForm app. VS2017 didn't come with that, from what I recall

Comment: Yes, WinForms on NetCore is recent stuff

Comment: @Steve, if you'll put that in as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Let's give @kshkarin the first shot.

Comment: @Steve thanks, answer posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2019 supports .NET Core templates for `WinForms` projects on project creation screen, to add `References` right click on `Dependencies` and `Manage NuGet Packages` then search for the required package.

If you create a .NET Framework WinForms project it still has `References` in the solution explorer.

Comment: Thanks. I added comments to my original question showing how I used this to solve my question.